# Instead of no rows the query should return rows with null values in columns

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
   PERSON_NAME 
FROM 
   PERSON 
WHERE 
   PERSON_ID = (SELECT ID FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE PERSON_ID = 123)
```

Now, when a valid `person_id` is present in `OTHER_TABLE` the value of `PERSON_NAME` is returned.

But when the `person_id` is not valid or is not present then it returns no rows. But instead I want it to return null for the person name.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: Probably not really relevant in this case, but still: you should tell us which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an outer join. For this you have to do some changes in your query. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT PERSON_NAME FROM PERSON P,OTHER_TABLE O 
WHERE P.PERSON_ID(+) = O.ID AND P.PERSON_ID = 123
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to return one row.  In that case, use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT MAX(PERSON_NAME)
FROM PERSON
WHERE PERSON_ID = (SELECT ID FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE PERSON_ID = 123);
```